# Protocol with associatedtype failed when being set downstream to generic parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol that has an associated, creating this protocol would to improve testability in my project.
My database manager is a singleton and mainly uses the functionality of a CoreData wrapper that also uses generics but I keep getting the following error message:

`Instance method 'addOf(type:properties:shouldSave:)' requires that 'ManagedObject' inherit from 'NSManagedObject'`

This is an oversimplification of the `CoreDataWrapper`:

```
class CoreDataWrapper {
    func addOf<M: NSManagedObject>(type: M.Type, properties: [String: Any], shouldSave: Bool) -> M? {
        nil
    }
}
```

This is the `DataBaseManager`:

```
final class DataBaseManager: DataBaseSyncOpManaging {

    static let shared = DataBaseManager()

    var wrapper = CoreDataWrapper()

    typealias ManagedObject = NSManagedObject

    func syncOpAddOf<ManagedObject>(
        type: ManagedObject.Type,
        properties: [String: Any],
        shouldSave: Bool
    ) -> ManagedObject? {
        wrapper.addOf(type: type, properties: properties, shouldSave: shouldSave)
    }

}
```

And this is the protocol I intend to create so that objects that use the `DataBaseManager` can just reference this protocol so that we can inject a mock object during testing:

```
protocol DataBaseSyncOpManaging: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ManagedObject

    func syncOpAddOf<ManagedObject>(
        type: ManagedObject.Type,
        properties: [String: Any],
        shouldSave: Bool
    ) -> ManagedObject?
}
```

I'm really not sure how to proceed here. Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks.

And here's a screen shot from Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In these two lines of code:

```
typealias ManagedObject = NSManagedObject
func syncOpAddOf<ManagedObject>(
```

I hope you realize that the term ManagedObject in the second line is totally unrelated to the term ManagedObject in the first line? It's just a placeholder; its spelling has no meaning. You'd be a lot less confused if you wrote

```
func syncOpAddOf<T>(
```

(and so on).

But what that proves, of course, is that the function should not be generic at all. This is more obvious for your protocol code. There is no point making the function generic; the protocol is *already* generic. You are making the function generic over a different type (spelled the same way), which is not what you mean at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply matt! You nailed it when you said that it wasn't required for the function to be generic. There was no misunderstanding because of nomenclature  I just don't like to use "T" I prefer something more expressive but I can understand where someone might get confused with it. Cheers!